# Convert tf.variable_scope to tf.keras.layers.Layer with reuse flag

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to convert a model with tf.variable_scope trained in tf1. I know how to do this but when a tf.variable_scope includes reuse=True or False i don't know how to convert it. My question is, if i simply ignore this flag, is my model going to be the same? Was that flag being used only for memory purposes?

Comment: This really depends on your model. Variable scope is used in TF1 and no longer there in TF2 (it might still be there for compatibility purposes, but not recommended). The purpose of Variable scope is that you can "scope" your variables. For example you can have the same name for the variable but different scope (e.g. layer1/w, layer2/w, etc.). Which provides intuitive names and structure when you want to retrieve variables.

Comment: @thushv89 so if i define a variable inside a scope and then define the same variable with the same scope but reuse=False, the initial one will be discarded and the new one will take place?

Comment: in TF1 you will get an error saying the variable already exists.